# Please Explain “|$y−π|\geq 2$” for me. I had a problem on a quiz that’s answer came out to this, but I don’t get why

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m supposed to give an inequality for “y is at least two units from pi” But I don’t get why $|y−π|\geq 2$ is the answer

Comment: because we use $|\cdot|$ as our distance

Comment: What’s an algebraic expression for how far $y$ is from $\pi$? And don’t forget that $y$ could be either side of $\pi$.

Comment: The distance two numbers are away from each other is given by the absolute value of their difference. In this case our two numbers are $y$ and $\pi$. So, $|y-\pi|$, as the absolute value of the difference between $y$ and $\pi$, will give us the distance $y$ is away from $\pi$. With this in mind, consider what it means for $|y-\pi|$ to always yield a value greater than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a sense of "distance" when you subtract two numbers. For example, $5-2=3$, tells us that there are $3$ units between $5$ and $2$.

What happens when we take $2-5=-3$? We expect the number of units between $2$ and $5$ to be the same as the number of units between $5$ and $2$. However, we see that the difference is $-3$ instead.

We are close, but we need to refine this notion of distance between numbers.

Notice that the *magnitude* (think of it as intrinsic size) of the difference remains the same in both cases. That is,

- $2$ can jump $3$ units *up*($+$) to $5$. We see that in $5-2=3$.
- $5$ can jump $3$ units *down*($-$) to $2$.  We see that in $2-5=-3$.

Either way, both numbers travel a *distance* of $3$ units to get to each other. We do not care for the direction (*up*/*down*) each number moves. We would need some operation to turn everything positive (since distance should be a positive value). That way, $-3$ becomes $3$ and $3$ remains unchanged, giving us a consistent distance value of $3$.

With this in mind, we can define the distance between $2$ and $5$ to be equal to $$|5-2|=|2-5|=3.$$

The vertical bars around an expression like $|x|$ denote the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of $x$. You should look at the definition(s) of it, but it effectively "removes" any negative sign $x$ may have just as we desired.

In general, the distance between two real numbers $x,y$ is defined as equal to the non-negative real number
$
|x-y|.
$

---

Looking at your problem, we see from above that $|y-\pi|$ denotes the number of units (distance) between $y$ and $\pi$. We want this value to be *at least* $2$ (it may be larger), so we state $|y-\pi|\ge2$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It effectively guarantees the number is *non-negative*; $|x - x| = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: It seems my own understanding of the absolute value is not thorough... thank you for the correction.

Comment: No, I am just nitpicking on minor details; this is a perfectly good answer!

Answer (score 1):

"At least" can be translated as meaning "greater than or equal to" (just think about how we use the phrase "at least" in everyday language). In particular, if $a$ and $b$ are two quantities, and if $a$ is at least as much as $b$, then we say $a\geq b$. This is because if $a = b$ then we have that the quantities are exactly the same; while, if $a>b$ then obviously we mean this as saying that "$a$ is greater than $b$." Also, as @FShrike (and others) correctly pointed out: often the absolute value $|\cdot |$ is used to denote distance. This means that if you want to denote the inequality "$y$ is at least two units from $\pi$," you would use $|y-\pi|\geq 2$, as this represents a distance from $\pi$ that is at least 2.